# Python.net doesn't work from python => .NET with named parameters?

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net

I have a .NET 4.7.2 assembly with a class in it and a method. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar(double duration, string ledPower, string gain, string exposure, string color) { }
}
```

I want to call it from python 2.7 using pythonnet. This works if the call is:

```
foo.Bar(1.2, '40', '50', '60', 'blah')
```

but not if it is using named parameters/kwargs:

```
foo.Bar(duration=1.2, ledPower='40', gain='50', exposure='60', color='blah')
```

The error says:

> TypeError: No method matches given arguments

This all works with IronPython internally - now I want to run from the CLI using CPython. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it make a difference at all if you change the signature from `double` to `float`?

Comment: The [code that does this](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/src/runtime/methodbinder.cs#L278) appears to ignore keyword arguments entirely, as far as I can tell. It at least doesn't appear to make any effort to match the keyword arguments with the managed method parameter names. I'm no Python expert, but if the keyword args (dictionary) do not preserve the parameter order, I don't think this code will manage to match.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I might have to see if I can make a fix to that. In the mean time, I wonder if I can add an overload that will work, perhaps a dict?